# How to use more than two monitors on Lubuntu 20.10

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors

Today I installed Lubuntu 20.10 and immediately noticed an issue, it can only recognize one external monitor at once.

I have a big hub with a bunch of USB ports and a couple of DisplayPorts. When I was using Windows it could detect up to four monitors including the laptop's built-in monitor.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I went into my monitor settings and it only recognized the monitor plugged directly into the laptop and the laptop's built-in monitor, not the ones plugged into the hub.

My graphics card is listed as `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)` when i use the command `lspci | grep VGA`.

The Hub is Kensington SD3500v USB 3.0 Docking Station. It appears to be display link but I can't find much information on display link for lubuntu. Since i heard that changing drivers to incorrect versions can brick your system I'd prefer to be sure that it's safe to do so.

Can I get some help fixing this?

Comment: Is the hub using video output over USB-C or DysplayLink technology? Maybe better to add the hardware specifications (hub) to your question as well.

Comment: i know it's not usb-c but i'm not sure about display link i'll have to look into it

Comment: If it uses DisplayLink then you need to install proprietary drivers. Windows probably has some version of it by default.

Comment: it appears to be display link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DisplayLink drivers are available for Ubuntu 20.04 - May not work for Ubuntu 20.10**

Before starting disconnect the hub.

[Download](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu) and extract the .run file anywhere (the subsequent [instructions](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1944022-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu-20-0) assume the file is at the root of your /home/user). Right-click > Properties and tick "allow execute..."

Open the Terminal and

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms
sudo apt install libdrm-dev

sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.4.0-55.153.run
```

Reboot before reconnecting the hub.

Comment: When i got to the final line it gave me the following error ` sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.4.0-55.153.run
sudo: ./displaylink-driver-5.4.0-55.153.run: command not found`

Comment: And are you in the location where that file is? I explicitly mentioned the instructions assume your terminal is open in the same location, otherwise `cd` accordingly. EDITED: It may also need execute permissions. Please refer to the edited answer.

Comment: you said it should be in home/user right? the user refers to the folder with your username right?

Comment: Yes. If you extracted it there the command should work provided you also make the change I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: there is no option for allow execute the closest thing is under the permisions tab which is "make the file executable". I checked that off but it still complains. Edit: i noticed a folder called displaylink debian in my home/username

Comment: That is the option and if the file is really where your terminal is then what exactly is the error message? It can't be "command not found". I actually tested it and it runs fine.

Comment: I don’t see QTerminal in home/username

Comment: "I don’t see QTerminal in home/username" and this is supposed to mean what exactly? You need to have the terminal open WHERE the displaylink....run file is. Either copy it to the default location where the terminal opens (/home/username) or cd into the folder where the file actually is now. It's not hard, it's basic CLI skills that I shouldn't have to be spoon-feeding, honestly.

Comment: If you don’t believe me I’ll take a screenshot of it being there because it is

Comment: Again... IF in the Terminal you're in the SAME folder as the .run file and previously made it executable (right-click > permissions), then `sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.4.0-55.153.run` runs it. That's all.

Comment: here’s a photo since the internet is acting wonky https://m.imgur.com/a/trtfY7j (updated to show everything)

Comment: Yes, it shows the FOLDER ("Displaylink USB...") at the root of your /home/user... The .run file is inside that folder.

Comment: Thank you it’s working now

Comment: Did it work with the additional monitors after rebooting? If so great and please accept the answer.

Comment: it only partailly worked. the screens now display properly but i cannot move the task bar from my laptop screen to an screen i actually use.

Comment: That should be in system settings > screens.

Comment: It’s working now